# forecast v7 & ggplot2 graphics adding fitted line to autoplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, forecasting

I was looking through a tutorial by Rob J Hyndman, here's [the link for the tutorial](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecast7-ggplot2/), my question is how can i add a fitted line to the forecast plot eg;

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
fc <- forecast(fdeaths)
autoplot(fc)
```

I now need to add `fitted(fc)`to the plot above, how do I do it?

Comment: `autoplot(fc) + geom_line(aes(y = fitted(fc)), col = "red")`

Comment: when I try this, I get the this error:  <Error in order(data$PANEL, data$group, data$x) :argument 3 is not a vector>

Comment: My bad, add `library(ggfortify)` before you plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an other solution without additional packages:

```
fit <- data.frame(data=as.matrix(fitted(fc)), date=time(fitted(fc)))
autoplot(fc) + geom_line(data = fit,aes(date,data), col = "red")
```

You transform your ts into a data frame where you can use normal ggplot command. You can then just add the line.
I realized that my solution work if the package ggfortify is not loaded