# Autoplot function behaves differently when I load ggfortify

Tags: r, ggplot2, forecasting, ggfortify

I want to plot graphs for various Forecast models.

When I use autoplot after loading ggplot2, the plot appears like this:

```
autoplot(m_hw1_ff)
```

[image]

I also want to add the fitted lines for training and test data. For that I am using the below code:

```
autoplot(m_hw1_ff) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=m_reg1_ff$fitted), col = "green") +
  geom_line(data=test_ts_data, aes(y=test_ts_data), col = "red")
```

When the above code is run after just loading ggplot2, it gives the following error:

```
Error in order(data$PANEL, data$group, data$x) : 
  argument 3 is not a vector
```

After referring to the comments and answers on this question, I loaded the ggfortify package as well.

[forecast v7 & ggplot2 graphics adding fitted line to autoplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49129594/forecast-v7-ggplot2-graphics-adding-fitted-line-to-autoplot)

The code works fine after that and the fitted lines for training and test data are plotted perfectly. However the shaded region, which was previously blue (dark and light for Lo 80, Hi 80, Lo 95 and Hi 95) has turned grey completely as in the graph below:

[image]

I want the shaded to region to appear as it appeared in the first graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

The first plot is plotted using

```
forecast:::autoplot.forecast
```

the `autplot` method for `forecast` objects from the package `forecast`

when you load `ggforitify` it is masked by:

```
ggfortify:::autoplot.forecast
```

and this is why the plots behave differently.

My recommendation is to convert the prediction objects to data frames and plot using ggplot. This will allow a much higher level of customization. Example:

```
library(forecast)
library(ggfortify)

d.arima <- auto.arima(AirPassengers)
d.forecast <- forecast(d.arima,  h = 50)
```

create a data frame for plotting:

```
for_plot <- ggfortify:::fortify.forecast(d.forecast,
                                         ts.connect = TRUE)
```

you can just do also:

```
 for_plot <- fortify(d.forecast, 
                     ts.connect = TRUE)
```

after loading `ggfortify`.

I just wrote it as above so you would understand what is called.

The `for_plot` object is a data frame, not in long format which ggplot likes. Nor in a format that is friendly for conversion to long, but it is manageable:

Example without conversion to long format (the ggplot heretic way):

```
ggplot(data = for_plot) +
  geom_line(aes(x= Index, y = Data, color = "raw")) +
  geom_line(aes(x= Index, y = Fitted, color = "fitted")) +
  geom_line(aes(x= Index, y = `Point Forecast`, color = "point forecast")) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x= Index, ymin = `Lo 80`, ymax = `Hi 80`,  fill = "80"),  alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x= Index, ymin = `Lo 95`, ymax = `Hi 95`,  fill = "95"),  alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual("what", values = c("blue", "dodgerblue"))+
  scale_color_manual("why", values = c("blue", "red", "green"))
```

[image]

The ggplot way would include spiting the data to two data frames, one for plotting the ribbon and the other for plotting the lines, converting each to long format and then plotting. Something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

for_plot_lines <- for_plot %>%
  gather(key, value, 2:4) %>%
  select(key, value, Index)

for_plot %>%
  filter(!is.na(`Point Forecast`)) %>%
  gather(Lo, ymin, c("Lo 80", "Lo 95")) %>%
  gather(Hi, ymax, c("Hi 80", "Hi 95")) -> for_plot_ribbon

ggplot(data = for_plot_lines) +
  geom_line(aes(x= Index, y = value, color = key)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = for_plot_ribbon,
              aes(x= Index, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = Hi), alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I thought that the method was getting overridden but just wasn't able to sort it out. The ggplot method however solved all the problem. Also, as you have stated, it lets me customise the graph as per my needs.